# Validator 'numeric' only accepts positive integers

Tags: apex

I'm writing an validation in apex, The name of the validator implies it is looking for any numeric value, discard the negative values. The current logic returns true even though its a negative integers.
What I like to do is to validate only positive number and throw an error if its a negative.

```
Integer betweenDays = -15;
Integer seven = 7;
boolean checkDays = betweenDays <= seven;
system.debug(checkDays); //it should return false since its a negative -15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `checkDays` to be `false` when `betweenDays` is negative, simply add that condition.

```
Boolean checkDays = betweenDays > 0 && betweenDays <= seven;
```